# How can I add styling to a DOM node using Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have some javascript code that looks like this:

```
dojo.query("#maintenanceOpData tr").forEach(function(node, index, nodelist){
    if (index % 2 == 0) {
        dojo.style(node, {
            "backgroundColor": "#FFFFCC"
        });
    };
});
```

Everything I find in online documentation shows that dojo.style expects the ID of the DOM element, not the DOM node itself. What can I do? The only other examples show using dojo.query(...).style(...), which applies the style to all nodes. I only want to apply it to every other node, which is why I use the for-each call.

Comment: Do it like this. Include a script tag like this: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` then in another script tag do `$('#maintenanceOpData tr:odd').style({backgroundColor:'#ffc'})` :P

Comment: ...I was being sarcastic. (oh well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Dojo are you using? Like JIP says, the code you've pasted should work fine ( http://jsfiddle.net/4HXMF/ ), given that you're using a recent version of Dojo.

Dojo query actually supports many of the new selectors, so you can in fact do:

```
dojo.query("#maintenanceOpData tr:nth-child(odd)").style("backgroundColor", "#FFFFCC");
```

Comment: That did the trick. I didn't know about the nth-child sub-option.

Answer (score 2):

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/style.html

> ```
> dojo.style(node, style, value);
> ```
>
> **node**:
>    id *or* reference of the DOM node to get/set style for

EDIT: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/wjUuY/)